# How to express in a shorter form that a task begins at 8:00 AM and ends at 5:00 PM?

Tags: word-request

Can I say "the task spans from 8:00 AM to 5:00 PM"?
The dictionary says "span" also means "a period of time", so it should be OK, but I'd like a confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Span is ok, but "from" is not.

"Span" is not generally used with "from".  "The bridge spans the Columbia River" or "The assignment spans 2 months."

So you could say "the task spans one working day (8am to 5pm)" or "the task runs from ..." or "the task extends from ..."

Also, be aware that you are using span as a verb here, not a noun - see [definition 13](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/span):  to extend or reach over (space or time).

Comment: Thank you, John, could you suggest a better word that can properly be used as a verb?

Comment: Span is fine - just drop the from/to construct.  Or use "run" or "extend" as I indicate in the 3rd line.

Comment: For what it's worth, *span from ... to ...* is not entirely impossible, e.g., *[The cargo preference year spans from April 1 of one year to March 31 of the next year and was created to measure compliance of food aid cargoes with the cargo preference requirements spelled o in the Food Security Act of 1985.](https://books.google.com/books?id=ngUNAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA26)*

Comment: A task takes an amount of time to do or be performed. That said, usually, a task does not take an entire day. An event or meeting takes that amount of time: The event (or conference or meeting) runs or goes from 8:00 am to 5:00 pm. VERSUS: the task takes 8 hours to complete. Eight hours are needed to perform the task. Task + span are not usual collocations (words found together) for the meaning you are seeking to impart here. Of course, you can say:the task spans an 8 hour time period. Again, no usual.

Answer (score 3):

I would say "The task **lasts** from eight to five".

Comment: This is a much better suggestion, could you not provide a dictionary link for our friend, who is obviously a learner?